# C# DisplayAttribute.GetName with specific culture

Tags: c#, localization

Suppose we have an enum:

```
public enum Foo 
{ 
   [Display(ResourceType = typeof(ModelStrings), Name = "Foo_Bar_Name")]
   Bar,
   [Display(ResourceType = typeof(ModelStrings), Name = "Foo_Far_Name")]
   Far 
}
```

And we have the resource `ModelStrings` with multiple locales.

```
ModelStrings.en-US.resx, ModelStrings.pt-BR.resx, ModelStrings.fr-FR.resx, etc..
```

How can I do something like this, to retrieve the resource value of a specific culture?

```
Foo myEnum = Foo.Bar;

var displayName = myEnum.GetDisplayName("pt-BR");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of reflection nicely provided as an extension method over `Enum` type can do the trick, since every resource, per default, has an public static instance of the `ResourceManager` class, responsible for managing resources.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
// ...

public static class EnumExtensions
{ 
     public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enumValue, string cultureName)
     {
         return GetDisplayName(enumValue, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultureName ?? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name));
     }

     public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enumValue, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
     {
         var attribute = enumValue.GetType().GetMember(enumValue.ToString())[0].GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();

         var resourceType = attribute.ResourceType;
         var resourceKey = attribute.Name;

         var resourceManagerMethodInfo = resourceType.GetProperty(nameof(ResourceManager), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

         var resourceManager = (ResourceManager)resourceManagerMethodInfo?.GetValue(null);

         return resourceManager?.GetString(resourceKey, cultureInfo);
     }
 }
```

So, we can simply use it like this:

```
Foo myEnum = Foo.Bar;

var displayName = myEnum.GetDisplayName("pt-BR"); // The extension method.
```

Tested on .NET Core 3.1